# Creating a life system like video games on a quiz

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating some web pages for an escape game. They mostly serve to gather responses and check if they are correct. In this case, it is a letter to put in the right order. The sorting script was taken from Codepen, then I've modified some JavaScript to monitor the if/else condition. If it is wrong, you loose a life. The code does that is the answer is wrong, it deletes one of the four images representing the life.

I've searched everywhere how to build a life system, so I tried some theories I've made in my mind, but I'don't have a good understanding of JavaScript yet to achieve what I want to do.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable();
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});

function checkOrd() {
  var life = document.getElementById('life');
  var items = $('#sortable li').map(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).attr('id'));
  }).get();
  var itsort = $('#sortable li').map(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).attr('id'));
  }).get();
  <!-- console.log(items); -->
  <!-- console.log(itsort); -->
  itsort.sort();
  if (JSON.stringify(items) == JSON.stringify(itsort))
    alert("Right order!");
  else
    life.parentNode.removeChild(life);
};
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>

  <img id="life" src="life.png"><img id="life" src="life.png"><img id="life" src="life.png"><img class="life" src="life.png"> </div>

  <div class="Lettre">
    <ul id="sortable">
      <li class="intro">INTRO TEXT</li>
      </br>

      <li class="partie" id="3">TEXT </li>

      <li class="partie" id="2">TEXT </li>

      <li class="partie" id="4">TEXT </li>

      <li class="partie" id="1">TEXT </li>

      <li class="outro" id="5">ENDING TEXT</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div class="confirmbutton" style="display: flex !important;justify-content: center !important">
    <button id="confirm" onclick="checkOrd();">Confirmer</button>
  </div>

  </html>
```

Is there a better way to handle this? If I work like that, I still haven't found a way to report the remaining life in the next pages.

Comment: Hi @Xy.  Not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish, but it looks like you might have some syntactical errors.  Shouldn't `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js</script>` be `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: Oh, typo from when I coppied the code here. It's edited, thank you :)

I'm trying to monitor the user input to see if he ordered the paragraphs in the right order, when the user confirms the order he arranged, he will be send to the next page if it's right, or he will lose a "life" just like in videogames if the order the paragraphs is incorrect. Then, I want to report the life count on the next page (if he has 2 or 3 life remaining, for example.)

Comment: I've converted your code sample into a runnable snippet, and corrected the typo discussed above (which was not corrected by your edit, you were missing a closing `"`). If that typo _was the actualy problem,_ please let us know.

Comment: Oh no it wasn't, actually it was just to check if how I proceeded was correct for that kind of situation and find a way to keep the life count on next pages, but I have to try Mendrika's function to see if it suits my needs ! Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically how you can do it:

```js
function removeLife(){

    $(".life").last().remove();

}

function countLives(){
  return $(".life").length;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <style>
    #lives{
      padding:0;
    }
    .life{
      display: inline;
    }
  </style>
<body>
  <ul id="lives">
    <li class="life">Life 1</li>
    <li class="life">Life 2</li>
    <li class="life">Life 3</li>
    <li class="life">Life 4</li>
  </ul>
  <button onclick="removeLife()">Remove a life</button>
  <button onclick="alert(countLives())">Get remaining lives</button>
  
</body>

</html>
```

You can then check how many lives are left with something like

```
function countLives(){
   return $(".life").length;
}
```

Comment: Because of my low reputation, i cant still add a comment to the original question so i must put it here. Id attribute should be unique. You should'nt assign the life id to the 4 img. (Use class instead). Id should also start with a letter.

Comment: Thank you ! Looks more functional than what I did. Though the button deletes a life no matter what. If the first script returns the alert "Right order" it shouldn't remove a life (as it is made now). I have yet to try the last function when I implement the next pages, but it looks perfect for what I need.

Comment: That's because you asked how to make a life system, not how to implement the whole game logic. I just showed you how to remove and count lives. You can for example add a test like if(user_isRight) { //do what you want } else { removeLife();}

Comment: If it suites your question, you can mark it as the accepted answer to close your question...(most new member forget to do it).

Comment: Wonderful ! Thank you so much ! Sorry I'm kinda new to coding so explaining exactly what I want to achieve is a bit confusing.

Comment: Unfortunately, the countLives() function wouldn't work, I'm trying to make it work with localStorage. but with no success...

Comment: @Xy. I updated the answer to show you that the countLives() function will give you the number of lives in the current page with an integer value, it's then up to you to do what you want with it. You should accept my answer back because based on your question, it fully answered it... You didn't explecitly ask how to bring it to the next page, plus you should ask a single specific question per post.

Comment: I'll guess I'll accept it, though the lifes restart when you refresh the page so it's still not fully answering my question. Thanks for your time though I really appreciated it, I just tought that removing the acceptance would open the thread to other answers, I'll just repost a question then.

Comment: Search for a similar question, i'm absolutely sure there is already something about storing data in the browser with java script. Avoid asking question the most, and ask single specific question.  High detailed and backed with code. Read the site rules. ... The term close i used is misleading, the question doesn't technically close and everyone can still answer if they have better approach but when someone will see your post is already answered, they can focus on other non answered questions.